# C# property inaccessible

Tags: c#

Why can I not have a private `struct` and then create a public property from it?

I get a 'property PubTest is less accessible than test' when I compile.

E.g.:

```
private struct test
{
    int a;
    double b;
}

test t = new test();

public test PubTest
{
     get { return t; }
}
```

Comment: If it's publicly available, why make it private?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Outside calling code has to know the return type of the property.

If the `struct` is made private, it can't be seen from the outside.

Comment: ok! So how do I keep the struct internal if I still want to have a property from it?

Comment: It doesn't make logical sense to keep the `struct` private if outside calling code needs to use it. What is the reason you want to make it private? That might help us find you a solution.

Comment: If you still want to define test inside of the containing type, but exposed properties of type test from that containing type, make test public. Without resorting to wrapping an instance of the private type, there's not really any way around the accessibility issues. Perhaps you should edit your question with details about what you're trying to accomplish at a higher level?

Comment: yes, you're right, it's pointless having it private if I need access to it from the outside.  What I wanted was readonly access to the members of this struct outside the class its in.  That's why I was trying to hide it and only have a getter property

Comment: Having a get on the property says only that you can't set *on the property*; however, you could still access the members of the returned object. I think what you want to do is make the members of the struct private (I assume you will expose other things publicly on the struct so that the outside property is useful).

Comment: @Tony: See my response (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882922/c-property-inaccessabile/1883088#1883088) for a mechanism to control who can read and write the fields of the struct.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expose the struct itself if it's private, but you can expose members of it:

```
public int TestA
{
    get { return t.a; }
    set { t.a = value; }
}

public double TestB
{
    get { return t.b; }
    set { t.b = value; }
}
```

That's about the best you can do here.

Answer (score 2):

> yes, you're right, it's pointless having it private if I need access to it from the outside. What I wanted was readonly access to the members of this struct outside the class its in. That's why I was trying to hide it and only have a getter property

If you need to control the access to the fields of a struct, then you can decorate thet `get` or `set` method with an access modifier as follows.

```
public struct Test
{
    private int a;
    private double b;

    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        internal set { a = value; }
    }

    public double B
    {
        get { return b; }
        internal set { b = value; }
    }
}
```

The `internal` modifier restricts access to the code in the assembly for which the encompassing type is defined.  Using `private` would restrict the access to the methods on the struct.

Comment: The `internal` modifier does not necessarily restrict access to a member in the way the OP intended.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `struct` is private, it is accessible only to the type containing it (which you didn't show in your example, but which I'll call `T` for brevity). If `T` has a public property, the consumer of that property must, perforce, have access to the type that is returned from the property... but it doesn't, because you declared that type as private to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you think that setting "private" on the struct changes the default access level for the members.  That is *not* what happens at all.  The default access level of all the members of the struct is still public; they can be seen anywhere your new struct type can be seen.

What does change is that the struct type itself is private; it's visible only to the class where you declared it (and it must be in a class rather than a namespace, because you can't declare it as private in a namespace).  It can't be accessed outside of there at all.  That means you have to be careful even using the struct in that assembly.  If a public or internal type in the assembly returns it from a public or internal method, you are potentially exposing it to the world outside of where it's allowed to be used, and that's a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, the structure needs to be at least as visible as the property.  If you only want to expose fiends of the structure to outside code, you can use something like this:

```
    private class Test
    {
        public int MyInt = 1;
        public double MyDouble = 2d;
    }

    Test test = new Test();

    public int PubTest
    {
        get { return test.MyInt; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

Use interfaces?

```
public interface ITest
{
    int a { get; }
    double b { get; }
}
public class MyClass
{
    private struct test : ITest
    {
        private int _a;
        private double _b;

        public int a 
        { 
            get { return _a; }
        }

        public double b 
        { 
            get { return _b; }
        }
    }
    public ITest PubTest
    {
        get { return new test() as ITest; }
    }
}
```